# How to set folder path variable in cookiecutter json file

Tags: jinja2, cookiecutter

I am using a [cookiecutter](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter) template with a json file like this:

```
{
    "full_name": "Your name",
    "email": "Your address email (eg. you@example.com)",
    "project_name": "Project name",
    "project_slug": "{{cookiecutter.project_name.lower().replace(' ', '-')}}",
    "project_desc": "Project description",
    "git_remote": "Git repository (if known)",
    "start_date": "{% now 'local' %}"
}
```

I wonder if there is a way to add a variable that retrieve the path to the folder generated by cookiecutter. I guess we could use something like this:

```
"folder_path": "{% pwd %}"
```

But this command does not work and I am not sure how to set it. The code in brackets is in jinja2. Thanks for the help !